# Delphi - Calculating Amazon MWS signature

Tags: delphi, amazon-mws, delphi-10.2-tokyo, ipworks

Using:
Delphi 10.2.3 Tokyo
IPWorks SSL and IPWorks Encrypt components

I am trying to use the Amazon MWS API from Delphi to get a list of orders, but am unsuccessful in making the request to Amazon MWS. Its mandatory that I use IPWorks components, as required by my client. The response from the API says that the signature is not correct:

> **Sender
> `SignatureDoesNotMatch`
> The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing
> method. Consult the service documentation for details.**

Obviously the issue has something to do with calculating the signature, encoding it to Base64, or something wrong with the request itself. I think its the encoding to Base64 that is not working for me. Maybe something to do with Delphi Unicode and UTF-8 encoding.

I've spent a whole day trying to figure this out and am stuck, so am posting it here. I hope someone can help. Below is my code:

On the form I have 2 components:  TipwHTTP and TipcHash

```
object HTTPS: TipwHTTP
  FollowRedirects = frAlways
  SSLCertStore = 'MY'
  OnTransfer = HTTPSTransfer
end

object HashMaker: TipcHash
  Algorithm = haHMACSHA256
  EncodeHash = True
end


function GetISO8601DateTime_URLEncodedStr(const ADateTime: TDateTime): String;
var
  d: String;
  l: Integer;
begin
  d := DateToISO8601(TTimeZone.Local.ToUniversalTime(ADateTime), True);
  l := Length(d);
  d := Copy(d, 1, l - 5) + 'Z'; // remove the milliseconds part

  Result := TNetEncoding.URL.Encode(d);
end;

const
  DOMAIN_NAME = 'https://mws.amazonservices.com/Orders/2013-09-01';
var
  sl: TStringList;
  param, signature, aurl: String;
begin
  sl := TStringList.Create;
  try
    sl.Add('AWSAccessKeyId=' + edtAwsAccessKey.Text); { Index: 0 }
    sl.Add('&Action=ListOrders'); { Index: 1 }
    sl.Add('&CreatedAfter=' + GetISO8601DateTime_URLEncodedStr(dtpOrdersCreatedFrom.Date)); { Index: 2 }
    sl.Add('&MWSAuthToken=' + edtMarketplaceID.Text); { Index: 3 }
    sl.Add('&MarketplaceId.Id.1=' + edtMarketplaceID.Text); { Index: 4 }
    sl.Add('&SellerId=' + edtSellerID.Text); { Index: 5 }
    sl.Add('&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256'); { Index: 6 }   // <---- Insert Signature here
    sl.Add('&SignatureVersion=2'); { Index: 7 }
    sl.Add('&Timestamp=' + GetISO8601DateTime_URLEncodedStr(Now)); { Index: 8 }
    sl.Add('&Version=2013-09-01'); { Index: 9 }

    param := StringReplace(sl.Text, #13#10, '', [rfReplaceAll]);

    HashMaker.Key := edtSecretKey.Text;
    HashMaker.Algorithm := haHMACSHA256;
    HashMaker.InputMessage := 'POST\n' + 'mws.amazonservices.com\n' + '/Orders/2013-09-01\n' + param;
    HashMaker.ComputeHash;
    signature := HashMaker.HashValue;

    SetStatus('Signature1: ' + signature);

    signature := TNetEncoding.Base64.Encode(TEncoding.UTF8.GetString(BytesOf(signature)));

    signature := TNetEncoding.URL.Encode(signature);

    SetStatus('Signature2: ' + signature);

    sl.Insert(6, '&Signature=' + signature);
    param := StringReplace(sl.Text, #13#10, '', [rfReplaceAll]);

    SetStatus('param: ' + param);

  finally
    sl.Free;
  end;

  with HTTPS do
  begin
    ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8';
    Accept := 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8';
    Timeout := 0;

    aurl := DOMAIN_NAME + '?' + param;
    Post(aurl);
  end;

end;
```

I would really appreciate if someone can help me solve this.

-Steve

Comment: What does the documentation instruct you to? At which point to do you fail? Is Base64 encoding just a wild guess from you? We are not Amazon - ask them for support.

Comment: @AmigoJack Yes I think its at the point of Base64 encoding.

Comment: @AmigoJack I'm pretty sure that the issue has something to do with the UTF-8 vs Unicode.

Comment: You need to encode the signature as BASE64 followed by URI Encode if using it as parameter in the URL  (since BASE64 uses + = and /).  Some date formats need to be URI Encoded as well.

Comment: @Brian Great. I will try that. I was not doing the last bit ie. URI encode. Thanks!

Comment: @Brian: I tried and not working. I've modified the code in my question to illustrate this.

Comment: Base64 the raw binary signature bytes not some UTF8 string or any string version of it. Ex something like `signature  := TNetEncoding.Base64.Encode(HashMaker.HashValueB);`

Comment: Might also need to turn off hex encoding the hash with `EncodeHash = false`. Not sure if it effects HashValueB or not (don't have IPWorks Encrypt myself to test).